# DotNetNuke Managing filtered words in Forum Module

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, forum

Is there a way to limit the Filtered word match in the dotnetnuke forum to whole words only. For example, if the word 'bum' is a filtered word replaced by a '~' then the word 'bumble bee' is also affected becoming '~ble bee'

I'd like to limit to a full word match rather than a partial. Any help is most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its been awhile but one trick I have done is but a space in the word you are filtering so it has to be bum_ not bumble (treat the underline char as a space in this post) -

Note: this used to work if DNN forum has changed to strip spaces off words in filter list this might not work anymore